# Why do we have $\{x_i^2\}$ has the same law that $\frac{g_i^2}{\sum_j g_j^2}$ for independent Gaussian random variables $g$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

When I read a textbook, it says that a random vector $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ follows the uniform law on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}_{\sqrt{n}}$ with radius $\sqrt{n}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Why do we have
$\{x_i^2\}$ has the same law that $$\frac{g_i^2}{\sum_j g_j^2}$$ for independent Gaussian random variables $g$. Here we represent $x=g/|g|$.

---

Also, since $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ follows the uniform law on the unit sphere. Can we have $x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2=n$?

Comment: What textbook ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability density function of $g$ depends only on the radius, and it is zero with probability $0$. So $g/\vert g\vert$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere, and $\sqrt n g/\vert g\vert$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere with radius $\sqrt n$.

Therefore $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $\sqrt ng/\vert g\vert$ follow the same distribution. By taking the square of the $i$-th marginal we then have that $x_i^2$ has the same law as $n g^2_i/\vert g\vert^2$. I believe that factor $n$ is missing in your question.

Also, of course $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2=n$ almost surely, that is the definition of belonging to the sphere with radius $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Is $g^2/|g|^2=g^2/n$?

Comment: Thanks! In fact, this question is from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445602/how-to-prove-that-sum-i-1ne-lambda-i-fracg-i2n-to-int-e-lambda-d. Can you please see it?

Comment: Also, If $g$ is not Gaussian, is $g/|g|$ uniformly distributed on the unit sphere? It seems that for any r.v. $g$, $g/|g|$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere.

Comment: No $g^2/\vert g\vert^2$ has no reason to be equal to $g^2/n$. And $g/\vert g\vert$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere because the probability density function of $g$ depends only on the radius. Basically this means that all directions in space are equally likely, so if you divide by the norm then you have something equally distributed on the unit sphere. Of course if we remove that property then it does not work. For example if $g$ is constant (not zero) then $g/\vert g\vert$ is a constant as well, and certainly not uniformly distributed on the unit sphere.

Comment: I mean whether g must be Gaussian, then this result is true? For example, how about $g$ is just a random variable not a constant?

Comment: How about $g$ is another random variable but not Gaussian?

Comment: If the probability density function of $g$ depends on the radius only, then yes. For example in two dimensions, if $g=(g_1,g_2)$ has a PDF proportional to $(x,y)\mapsto1/(1+x^2+y^2)$ then yes. If its PDF is for example zero for $x<0$ then of course not (there's no way to get the left side of the unit circle by dividing by the norm if everything happens for $x>0$)